# How to receive an activity result in a separate class with registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-fragmentactivity, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to launch a intent from a separate class of my FragmentActivity to show the Biometric Settings to help user to enroll a biometric. But I'm getting a null from the observer and I don't know why.

I'm following this guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=fr

This is my FragmentActivity code:

```
public class BiometricFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static FragmentActivity instance;
    public static ViewGroup viewGroupContent;
    private BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver mObserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.TransparentActivityTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.biometric_fragment_activity);
        instance = this;
        viewGroupContent = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mObserver = new BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver(instance.getActivityResultRegistry());
        getLifecycle().addObserver(mObserver);
        NavigationUtils.mListener.onCreated();

        if(BiometricUtils.canAuthenticate && BiometricUtils.needEnrollment){
            mObserver.openBiometricSettings();
        }
    }


}
```

and this is my lifecycle observer class:

```
public class BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    private final ActivityResultRegistry mRegistry;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mLauncher;

    BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver(@NonNull ActivityResultRegistry registry) {
        mRegistry = registry;
    }

    public void onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {

        mLauncher = BiometricFragmentActivity.instance.registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                        BiometricManager biometricManagerRetry = BiometricManager.from(BiometricFragmentActivity.instance);
                        if(biometricManagerRetry.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL) == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS){
                            BiometricUtils.canAuthenticate = true;
                        }else{
                            BiometricUtils.canAuthenticate = false;
                        }
                    }else{
                        BiometricUtils.canAuthenticate = false;
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    public void openBiometricSettings(){
        // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
        final Intent enrollIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL);
            enrollIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                    BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_FINGERPRINT_ENROLL);
        }else{
            enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
        }
        mLauncher.launch(enrollIntent);
    }
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException when launching "mLauncher.launch(enrollIntent)" from the BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver class.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3835)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4011)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver.openBiometricSettings(BiometricFragmentActivityLifecycleObserver.java:62)
        at BiometricFragmentActivity.onCreate(BiometricFragmentActivity.java:30)
```

Comment: Are you shure that onCreate() is called where mLauncher should be initialized?

Comment: The oncreate from fragmentactivity or from lifecycle?